# disabled enabled button using lotus formula

Tags: lotus-formula

I have two buttons "Button1" and "Button2". When I clicked "Button1", "Button1" should be invisible and "Button2" should be visible.When I clicked "Button2", "Button2" should be invisible while "Button1" should be visible. Meaning there will be a switching visibility of the two buttons. How can I do this using hide-when formula?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned where the buttons are located. If they're on a Form you can create a hidden field above the two buttons that you set the value of when you toggle. Then your Hide/When formula can reference this hidden field.

It's been a while since I've done any of this. When you "toggle" the field you need the Form to refresh/recalculate it's Hide/When formulas